# How to display user defined ToolTips in web page using ASP?

Tags: asp.net

I want to display all the "**ToolTips**" in my web page is user defined, like user defined BoxSize, ForeColor, BackColor, FontSize etc.

Could you please guide me how to do this, as I am new to ASP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use jQuery with a ToolTip plugin. Then you can customize your Tooltips very easy:

Here is a list of some jQuery Tooltip Plugins:http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/

Comment: Thank you.

Is it possible to implement it using JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: You will need both of it. Check out the documentation of the plugin you have choosen for it.